# AssmeblyScript function doesn't get called

Tags: typescript, assemblyscript

I have the following AssmemblyScript module:

```
export function add(a: i32, b: i32): i32 {
  return a + b;
}

export function printNum(a: string): f64 {
  return parseFloat(a);
}
```

Which is generated with `asc assembly/index.ts --target release`

I'm then consuming that in my host TypeScript files:

```
import fs from "fs";
import loader from "@assemblyscript/loader";
import { join } from "path";

const wasmModule = loader.instantiateSync(fs.readFileSync(join(__dirname, "..", "/build/untouched.wasm")), {});
module.exports = wasmModule.exports;
```

And I can call `add` just fine:

```
const { add, printNum } = require("./wasm");
console.log(add(1, 2)); // correctly prints 3
```

However, trying to call `printNum` doesn't crash my Node process, but the process exits successfully, without the code being called:

```
    const [row] = await db.getWhere({});
    console.log("balance", row.balance, typeof row.balance); // balance 123456789123456789.123456789123456789 string
    try {
      const result = printNum(row.balance);
      console.log("result", result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(add(1, 2));

    console.log("done");
```

The `printNum` function is never called, or it's called and internally errors? I don't receive any error in the `catch`, and the subsequent two console.logs are never called

If I comment out the whole `printNum` try/catch, those next two console.logs are executed

Where do I begin debugging this? Or can anyone spot any errors in my AssemblyScript `printNum` method itself that might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

`printNum` takes a pointer to a string. To create a new string use `__newString` and pass the returned pointer to `printNum`.

```
const { add, printNum, __newString } = require("./wasm");
const result = printNum(__newString(row.balance));
```

[Reference](https://www.assemblyscript.org/loader.html#usage)

Comment: You're right! Realised this after I posted. As an aside, do you know why `export function printNum(a: string): string {
  const num = <f64>parseFloat(a);
  const res: f64 = num + 1;
  return res.toString();
}` would return "123456789123456790.0" after being called like so: `const ptr = __newString(row.balance);
      const result = printNum(ptr);` ?

To me, passing in "123456789123456789.123456789123456789" should return "123456789123456790.123456789123456789"

Comment: an f64 can only hold a specific amount of precision. Just pasting the number in your dev console and printing it already truncates it.

Comment: got you! Does AssemblyScript contain a Number Type that would accommodate such a precision?

Comment: f64 is already a double. For everything else you would need something like `as-bignum` but that's still in early development.